# Registration page background color covering 1 screen not covering full page

Tags: wp-login-form

Good Day,
I have been researching this for a few days and cannot find a solution.  The website is http://gwendolinesroadtrip.com/

The background color of the registration page is not filling the entire page.  I have tried almost all suggestions without touching the original WordPress files or Twenty Twelve theme files. The plugins I am using are jonradio Private Site and Register Plus Redux.  I have removed them both but the problem is still there.

Thank you in advance for any help
Debbie

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you ought to look into your workstation, rather than the code. The page is loading fine :)

Chrome:
http://screencast.com/t/MczYhpM93

Firefox:
http://screencast.com/t/w4261DebfR

Safari:
http://screencast.com/t/BM4xxMBkq

IE:
http://screencast.com/t/TVlUlpZXwOB

I'm pretty sure Opera will do the same.

Comment: Hi There, Thank you for your reply.  That is the login screen, did you check the registration page?

Comment: You have a CSS issue on the registration page, but it isn't with the background: http://screencast.com/t/NH0ioyHw -- try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Thank you again.  I have cleared my cache and history, rebooted for the halibut.  On Chrome it was the same then I remembered that I use a bigger font.  Changed it back to 100 and now it is fine (except for where the writing is right up to the confirm password field.  On 2 computers using Firefox it is still wrong.  But thank you for making me think of my browser setting :)

Comment: Could someone please steer me in the right direction to solve this?

Comment: I mean, I'm not seeing what you are seeing so, I can't really help you any further. Your website works, your PC has a problem. It's sort of beyond the scope of this forum. Try asking over at http://superuser.com/questions

Comment: You do have a problem with the password field on the registration page. What plugin are you using to do these mods?

Comment: Thanks a Bunch for your help. Working offline and finding my mistakes.  I just get the html, css and php mixed up not knowing where I should be looking.  But more important I think I am getting it. :)  Yes it is definitely a problem with the plugins.  I think it is this one: Register Plus Redux.  Offline I am not using this and everything is fine.  This was a website that was rushed so I am starting over and properly.  Thanks again for your help, you DID help :D

Comment: There really isn't any need to add a third party plugin for this, although it's the sort of thing you would probably bundle into a functionality plugin (google it) in order to make it portable. Check out the WP-TutsPlus series on customizing your login and registration area: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/customizing-the-wordpress-admin-the-login-screen/

Comment: Thank you again.  Yes I found that out with working offline.  Finding many things that I had that I didn't really need.  I had never done a website that required login in so add that to the css and php OMG LOL.  Could you register to the site to check things out?  or it isn't necessary?  If you do, please use this ID so I will know you are ok LOL